# Do I run a 3-Way ANOVA on SPSS if one of my IV is just there to form a control group?

Tags: anova, spss, post-hoc, univariate

I'm trying to see what effect different doses of a drug (IV 1) have on the behavior (my dependent variable) of a rodent model; specifically, whether there is a significant change in this behavior compared to an animal given saline. I also want to see if there are sex differences (IV 2) for each dose group. All of these animals have been stressed, and as a control, I am using a group of animals given only saline that have not been stressed. I mainly want to make sure that there is a significant difference between this group and the stressed group that's been given saline (another control), but it would still be interesting to know if there's also a sig. difference between the other stressed groups and the non-stressed one.

So the way it's set up on SPSS, I have whether they have been stressed or not, whether they are male or female, and what dose they have been given (saline + 3 others).

**My main question is:**
Would the fact that they have been stressed or not make it a 3rd independent variable? Seeing that they'll only have 1 dose (Saline) for males and females in the non-stressed group, I don't know if that makes a difference. If not, could I just run a two-way ANOVA and input the non-stressed group as its own dose, making a total of 5 doses? I'm not sure if this is what i'm supposed to be doing in the first place.